# Resume click event after completion of login

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I am developing an application in which login is not mandatory, but in side app there are some events where app asks user to login. I want to resume the process once login is done. For example if user is not logged in and clicks on "like" button, app redirects user to login activity. Now i want after login is done "like" click will also be performed. There are more such type buttons, apart from like. Please help...

Comment: try to integrate using onStartActivityResult()

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this (fragments, static fields to share status and perform action other where etc..) But in my opinion using a `flag` and `startActivityForResult` is the best thing to do in such a situation and to ensure re-usability, you can map a set of events with a number of keys and call those instead of separated flags once you receive the proper key associated with the event

**HINT**: send them through `intents`.

I'll use a flag here so for example if you want the like to be performed after the user is logged in.

In your **CurrentActivity** the one with the like button, set up an instance `static boolean isValid=false;` then use:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Login.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

In **Login.class**:

```
 //perform login
    Intent i = new Intent();
    //reset isValid to true
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i);
    finish();
```

In **CurrentActivity.class:**

```
//re-trigger the click event 
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && isValid) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            //like
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: np, glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Login screen as `DialogFragment`, so it will act as a `Dialog` by this way you can handle the previous click event by using a callback method in that `Activity`.